# User confirmation from a formatted screen

Tags: google-apps-script

I developed an app that runs from a Spreadsheet.  It has a formatted screen, ie. doc.show(app 
).  There is a mass change function.  I'd like to prompt the user for 'Are you sure ... OK to Continue'.

The ideal solution would be a pop-up form with an "OK to continue" response.

I can't find a way to prompt the user and accept a response that doesn't simultaneously take down the formatted screen.

I know there must be a easy way to do this.  I searched this forum and others, but cannot find a solution that applies to Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 3):

When using the GUI Builder I've found a very simple solution that is to create a panel or a label that is actually masking the whole UI (or part of it) and that is normally invisible.
When I make it visible I can click on it, it turns invisible again and I'm back on the standard UI. It uses the ability in GUI builder to move elements backwards and forwards so masking is very easy (a sort of multi layer design). I guess the same behavior is achievable with script defined UI but I'm not sure how...
regards,
Serge

EDIT : For information : I just set up an interface using this technique and I noticed that panels that have been made invisible must be restored along with all their elements otherwise they reappear empty.  Using Clienthandlers here is an example with two panels and two buttons that do the job :

```
  var panhandler0 = app.createClientHandler()
     .forTargets(panel1).setVisible(false);// hide panel1 when button 'ENTER'on panel1 is pressed
   enter.addClickHandler(panhandler0);
  var panhandler1 = app.createClientHandler()
     .forTargets(panel2,msg,grid2).setVisible(true);// show panel2 when button 'ENTER' on panel1 is pressed
   enter.addClickHandler(panhandler1);
  var panhandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
     .forTargets(panel2,msg,grid2).setVisible(true);// re-show panel2 when button 'retry'on panel2 is pressed
  retry.addClickHandler(panhandler2);
  var panhandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
     .forTargets(panel2).setVisible(false);// hide panel2  when button 'retry'on panel2 is pressed
  retry.addClickHandler(panhandler3);
  var panhandler4 = app.createClientHandler()
     .forTargets(panel1,txt,grid,hpanel).setVisible(true);// re-show panel1 when button 'retry'on panel2 is pressed
```

Works nicely !

Comment: putting a panel on top is indeed much, much smarter.

Comment: Serge, can you please tell me how to include program code in a comment as you have done above. Thank you !!

Comment: Oh.  I don't seem to be able to make myself clear.  In this comment box, I can't even create a newline.  I'd like to show you some code to help explain my issue, but if I type it in this comment box, its unintelligible.  I need at least the ability to create a newline.  Do I need to 'answer' my own question to include some code examples ?

Comment: I guess there's no other way to proceed if you need to insert code (I don't think this would be an issue but I'm not an expert in StackOverflow 'good behavior', too new here !). Otherwise comments are just ... comments ;-)

Comment: Thank you Serge for your help.  I have implemented your suggestion using a DialogBox on a VerticalPanel, works great.  The only problem there is no general solution.  I put in a tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1360

Answer (score 1):

You can use Browser.MsgBox() and add buttons into it for users confirmation.
Refrence URL
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_browser

Comment: this does not work. The UiApp instance is not restored after the Browser.msgBox

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not an easy thing to do. You'll have to use your own GUI (formatted screen) to show the message. This way you can restore the state of your GUI again. Here is an example:

```js
function uiTest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("UI");
  app.add(app.createGrid(1,1).setId('main'));
  createGUI(app,{});
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);
}

function createGUI(app,p) {
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('handler').addCallbackElement(panel);
  panel.add(
    app.createTextBox().setName('text').setId('text').setText(p.text ? p.text : "")).add(
    app.createButton('Do it').addClickHandler(handler));
  app.getElementById('main').setWidget(0,0, panel);
}

function handler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var hidden = app.createHidden('oldValues', JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  app.getElementById('main').setWidget(0,0, app.createVerticalPanel().add(
    hidden).add(
    app.createLabel("Question message")).add(
    app.createButton('Ok').addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('after').addCallbackElement(hidden))));
  return app;
}

function after(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  createGUI(app,JSON.parse(e.parameter.oldValues));
  return app;
}
```

The difficulty will really depend on how much state you need to restore. If none, then it's a lot, lot easier. In this example I restore the value of the textbox. You can type in anything there to see that it will be there after the popup.

Comment: I have a lot of state info to restore: the application consists of a tab panel with 7 tabs, each a separate but interrelated function (eg. one sets a filter, another sends an email to everyone in the filter).  I'm looking for a MsgBox type screen that I can code inline in my application.  The problem is the this function necessarily uses 'return app' to display the dialog.  Doing so stops the execution of the calling function.  It seems that your solution will suffer the same fate ... no ?  Henrique, oh wise one, please tell me I'm missing something !

Comment: I can't find a way to cut and paste a code example, so I'll try to type one out.   (Two spaces does not seem to equal a return).  function massUpdate() { ... prepare for the update, edit user input etc ...  var response = myInlineMsgBox("Mass Update", "Are you Sure", OK_CANCEL)  if (response == "cancel" {do nothing} else { ... continue with the massupdate function ... } return app }

Comment: I understood nearly nothing of your comments. My code example is complete, were you not able to run it? Anyway, you should use Serge's approach, it is way, way more smart and easy to do.

Comment: When you call MsgBox, control passes to the MsgBox routine.  When the user clicks 'OK', control passes back to the next statement in the calling routine.  I want to do the same thing from a UiApp screen.

Comment: That is not possible. It's a different model, you have to "continue" your routine on the handler (a different function that is called when the 'Ok' is pressed). That's just how it works.

Comment: Thank you Henrique for your help, you're the best!  I submitted a Tracker for this.  I've never seen an interactive environment that didn't provide for this.  http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1360

Comment: I have managed to fashion a semi-general-purpose modal DialogBox.  I need to pass parameters to the 'OK to continue' routine.  I need to pass a 2D array.  I tried a 'Hidden' but an array doesn't seem to pass through it.  I tried JSON.stringify, but that seems to only take an object as an argument.  I started to use .join/.split, but conflict between data and delimiters would be a nightmare.  I haven't tried UserProperties, but I'm almost certain that they also will pass an array.  Anything in your bag of tricks for this ?

Comment: Henrique, please disregard the above.  Utilities.jsonStringify/parse do work on arrays.  Problem solved !!

Comment: My DialogBox routine seems to have a flaw.  It is displayed to ask the user if they are sure they want to continue with the mass update function.  After they click 'OK' to continue, there is no way to remove the Dialog box while the mass update processes.  The user can continue to click 'OK' and/or 'Cancel' any number of times.  I confirmed that the massupdate routine runs over and over again if the user keeps clicking OK.  I can't find a way to disable the 'OK' button or take down the form without also stopping the massupdate processing.

Perhaps I'm missing something.  @Serge