# Unexpected error Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a form, but now i get an unexpected error.

```
function showCompletePage(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('rightPanel').setVisible(false);
  var pnl = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('outro');
  var text = "<p>Uw aanvraag is met succes verwerkt.</p>";
  text += "<p>U zal zo meteen een offerte ontvangen via mail.<br />Verzeker u ervan dat de mail niet in uw spam toegekomen is.</p>";
  text += "<p>Gelieve de offerte binnen de drie dagen terug te sturen, zodat uw reservatie definitief bevestigd kan worden.</p>";
  pnl.add(app.createHTML(text).setId('final'));

  var el = app.createButton('Klik hier indien u nog een opleiding wil reserveren').setId('anotherOne');
  el.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("startAgain"));
  app.add(pnl);
  app.add(el);

  return app;
}

function startAgain(e){
  Logger.log('restart');
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('startAgain').setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById('outro').setVisible(false);
  buildUI();

  return app;
}
```

I already figured out that i don't get an error when i comment the line        `app.getElementById('outro').setVisible(false);`
in the function startAgain()

Someone who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Given your last comment, I don't think the element with Id of 'outro' exists or does not have the function setVisible();  That's been my experience.

Comment: The `app.getElementById('startAgain').setVisible(false);` is the strange line for me. I don't see any element id'ed `startAgain`. Are you sure it isn't the offending line?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested you exact code and it works here as expected... For test purpose I created an showCompletePage() function that shows another UI and I can actually switch from one to the other...
So maybe the error stands somewhere else ? in the showCompletePage part ?

here is the test code, your part is unchanged :

```
function buildUI() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(130).setWidth(400);
  app.setTitle("Search by name / lastname / adress");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('rightPanel');
  var txtBox = app.createTextBox();
  var label=app.createLabel(" Item to search for :")
  panel.add(label);
  txtBox.setId("item").setName("item");
  var label0=app.createLabel("Row").setWidth("40");
  var label1=app.createLabel("Name").setWidth("120");
  var label2=app.createLabel("Lastname").setWidth("120");
  var label3=app.createLabel("Street").setWidth("120");
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel.add(label0).add(label1).add(label2).add(label3)
//
  var txt0=app.createTextBox().setId("lab0").setName("0").setWidth("40");
  var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId("lab1").setName("txt1").setWidth("120");
  var txt2=app.createTextBox().setId("lab2").setName("txt2").setWidth("120");
  var txt3=app.createTextBox().setId("lab3").setName("txt3").setWidth("120");
  var hpanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel2.add(txt0).add(txt1).add(txt2).add(txt3)
  var hidden = app.createHidden().setName("hidden").setId("hidden");
  var subbtn = app.createButton("next ?").setId("next").setWidth("250");
  panel.add(txtBox);
  panel.add(subbtn);
  panel.add(hidden);
  panel.add(hpanel);
  panel.add(hpanel2);
//
  var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler("showCompletePage");
  subbtn.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  app.add(panel);  
  ss.show(app);
  }
//
function showCompletePage(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('rightPanel').setVisible(false);
  var pnl = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('outro');
  var text = "<p>Uw aanvraag is met succes verwerkt.</p>";
  text += "<p>U zal zo meteen een offerte ontvangen via mail.<br />Verzeker u ervan dat de mail niet in uw spam toegekomen is.</p>";
  text += "<p>Gelieve de offerte binnen de drie dagen terug te sturen, zodat uw reservatie definitief bevestigd kan worden.</p>";
  pnl.add(app.createHTML(text).setId('final'));

  var el = app.createButton('Klik hier indien u nog een opleiding wil reserveren').setId('anotherOne');
  el.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("startAgain"));
  app.add(pnl);
  app.add(el);

  return app;
}

function startAgain(e){
  Logger.log('restart');
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('startAgain').setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById('outro').setVisible(false);
  buildUI();

  return app;
}
```

Comment: Following Henrique's comment I re-tested my test code and it generates an error ( strangely it didn't on the first time).  As usual Henrique is right, the faulty line in my test code is   app.getElementById('startAgain').setVisible(false); sorry for not having point it out.

Comment: Also I think it's not really a good idea to call buildUI(); in your handler function 'start again' as it re-creates the UI entirely... would be more efficient to restore the existing one or to use a show/hide process (see this thread :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564565/user-confirmation-from-a-formatted-screen/10572034#10572034 )